# Manually Send Email Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I've been trying to implement the code from this question: [Send an email manually of a specific page in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545574/send-an-email-manually-of-a-specific-page-in-rails-app)

The only difference is that I need to fetch the email address from my model. This is usually no problem when sending emails from models.

```
UserMailer.report(self).deliver
```

But I want to click on a button in the show view of my record.

I need to manually send out emails using the details of the record in the email.

Maybe there is a better approach than using an extra controller for this?

```ruby
# app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ActionMailer
  def report(thing)
    @thing = thing
    mail :to => thing.email, :from => 'you@example.com', 
      :subject => 'that report you want'
  end
end

# app/views/user_mailer/report.html.erb
<h1>Report</h1>
<p>Here is your <% @thing.customer_id %></p>


# app/controllers/reports_controller.rb
def create
  UserMailer.report(@thing).deliver
  flash[:notice] = 'report sent!'
  redirect_to root_path # or wherever
end

# in a view
<% form_tag(reports_path(@thing), :method => :post) do %>
  <% submit_tag 'send report email' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm returning null with the code above:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create is a post request in rails, you cannot pass parameter like this you need to fetch from params. I'm seeing you are giving it a parameter which is wrong.

Secondly you are doing @thing = thing and then you are sending thing (without @) to report method of UserMailer which is also wrong, it would be be nil in report method. you should do UserMailer.report(@thing).deliver after @thing is an object which has email

Comment: How do I fetch from params?

Comment: so when create action is called, it means some form is being submitted from the view and something is being created and that form parameters you can see using p params in create action. so do p params in next line in def create. you will see params of report in rails server logs. then create @report = Report.new(params[:report]); report.save. if email exists in report object do this UserMailer.report(@report).deliver

Comment: Pleasehave a look at this one in point 4 Parameters to understand the actions and the way it works. I think it will help you http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html